# Проблема с кликами в js

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

Есть простой код:

```
<div id="r">0</div>
<button id="b" onclick="inc()"></button>
<script>
function my_click(){
document.getElementById("b").click();
}
my_click();
function inc(){
var val = parseInt(document.getElementById("r").innerHTML);
val++;
document.getElementById("r").innerHTML = String(val);
my_click();
}
</script>
```

Но, по какой-то непонятной причине, inc() срабатывает только раз. То есть, в диве появляется 1, и не более. Что я упускаю?

Comment: а что этот код делает? +2 к числу добавляет при нажатии кнопки?

Comment: При загрузке страницы отрабатывает my_click() и затем inc(). А inc() увеличивает значение в диве на 1 и вызывает клик, который потом опять вызывает inc(). Своеобразная рекурсия. Но почему-то она не работает.

Comment: `inc()` срабатывает только при нажатии кнопки, увеличивает на 1 `val` и затем вызывает `my_click()`. В результате, при одном нажатии на кнопку val увеличивается на 2, верно?

Comment: Так и есть. Но почему она срабатывает только раз? И как сделать так, как я хотел?

Comment: Честно говоря, пока никак не могу понять, что вы пытаетесь сделать) может быть при нажатии один раз кнопки, началось прибавление числа в течение некоторого времени? или как?

Comment: Хм, если закрыть тегом `</script>`, [работает по-другому](https://jsfiddle.net/f2y94xbu/).

Comment: Я хочу, чтобы при загрузке этой страницы значение в блоке увеличилось до максимально возможного, то есть, чтобы эти функции вызывали друг друга до тех пор, пока не переполнится стек. В этом нет никакого смысла, я просто учусь

Comment: Забыл вставить закрывающий тег, но в моем файле он есть

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ну вот как вариант добавить `setInterval`

```
function my_click(){
    document.getElementById("b").click();
}
    my_click();
    function inc(){
        setInterval(function () {
            var val = parseInt(document.getElementById("r").innerHTML);
            val++;
            document.getElementById("r").innerHTML = String(val);
            my_click()
        }, 100)
    }
```

с какой скоростью прибавлять, решаете сами конечно)

Comment: То что нужно, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Если нету никакого смысла и нужен просто стек вызовов, тогда прошу:

```
function my_click() {
    document.getElementById("b").click(); inc();
};
my_click();

function inc() {
    var val = parseInt(document.getElementById("r").innerHTML);
    val++;
    document.getElementById("r").innerHTML = String(val);
    my_click()
}
```